# Customize overrightarrow

Tags: math-mode, arrows

I would like to typeset an arrow over a pair of letters, in the way that overright does: i.e., as `\overright{PP'}`. However, I would like the arrow to be a different style: specifically, I would like to replicate the following:

[image]

(It doesn't need to be exactly like the above arrow, but I would like it to have the same triple-tail.) Is this possible?

Comment: Which package provides `\overright`?

Answer (score 3):

I do not know that symbol, but it is easy construct an arrow with triple tail with another math symbols:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, amsmath, amssymb}
\def\arrow3tails{%
\resizebox{2em}{!}{$\ggg\kern-1.1em\rule[2pt]{2em}{1pt}%
\kern-.4em\blacktriangleright$}}
\begin{document}
$\overset{\arrow3tails}{PP'}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use scriptscriptstyle `\succ` and the arrow in scriptstyle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\overrightarrowttt}[1]{%
  \mathord{%
    \vbox{%
      \m@th\offinterlineskip
      \ialign{%
        \hfil##\hfil\cr
        \rightarrow@ttt\cr
        \noalign{\kern0.4pt}
        $#1$\cr
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\ttt@joinrel}[1]{%
  \mathrel{\mspace{-#1mu}}%
}
\newcommand{\ttt@ail}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\succ$}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\rightarrow@ttt}{%
  $\scriptstyle
  \ttt@ail\ttt@joinrel{9}
  \ttt@ail\ttt@joinrel{9}
  \ttt@ail\ttt@joinrel{12}
  \relbar\ttt@joinrel{9}
  \rightarrow\ttt@joinrel{6}$
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\overrightarrowttt{PP'}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the package [overarrows](https://ctan.org/pkg/overarrows) to automate the answer given by egreg.

The requested arrow can be drawn with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{overarrows}

\newcommand*{\tttail}{\succ\xjoinrel[10]\succ\xjoinrel[10]\succ}

\NewOverArrowCommand{overtttailrightarrow}{%
  start={\vcenter{\hbox{$\smallermathstyle\tttail$}}},
  end={\rightarrow},
  trim start=12,
  shift left=0, shift right=0,
  space after arrow=.2ex,
  min length=24,
}

\begin{document}

$ \overtttailrightarrow{PP'} $

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image: overtttailrightarrow with overarrows package]

This defines the command `\overtttailrightarrow`. `\xjoinrel` and `\NewOverArrowCommand` are two macros from the `overarrows` package.

Comment: Welcome :-) and thank you for your answer. +1